# Преобразование элементов списка(строки) в ВЕРХНИЙ РЕГИСТР python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть следующий список:

```py
['фыа','ер','ук','рпап','прооп','фывф','уркпра','ыаываы','титит']
```

Значения в нём при каждом запуске будут разными

Как мне перенести строки в верхний регистр?

Comment: `"строка".upper()`

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'upper'   - я пытался

Comment: Напомню что надо лист(список) со всеми строками перенести в верхний регистр

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам необходимо применить метод строк `upper` к каждому элементу, попутно добавляя его в новый список. Удобнее всего сделать это с помощью генератора.

***Код:***

```py
li = ['фыа', 'ер', 'ук', 'рпап', 'прооп', 'фывф', 'уркпра', 'ыаываы', 'титит']

new_li = [x.upper() for x in li]
print(new_li)
```

***stdout:***

```py
['ФЫА', 'ЕР', 'УК', 'РПАП', 'ПРООП', 'ФЫВФ', 'УРКПРА', 'ЫАЫВАЫ', 'ТИТИТ']
```

---

### Замеры производительности

```py
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase
import timeit


li = [''.join(random.choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(32)) for _ in range(1000)]

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: [x.upper() for x in li]))   # 69.81857771100022
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: list(map(str.upper, li))))  # 49.37236840500009
```

Способ с использованием `map` в среднем на 30% быстрее, чем способ со списковым включением

Comment: Сейчас проверим

Comment: Собственно а что быстрее работает через map или цикл выше?

Comment: @hellog888 Через `map`. Замер привёл в ответ

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = ['фыа','ер','ук','рпап','прооп','фывф','уркпра','ыаываы','титит']

a = list(map(str.upper, a))

print(a)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).